# Replacing NAs by wither preceding or post value, group wise in R

Tags: r

Conside the following table.

```
MC  StartDate   EndDate LWID    KMT DAFR    FTR FSR
HP300805    08Nov2016 0:00:00.000   08Nov2016 0:00:00.000   25Sep2006 0:00:00.000   2403468.00000   872.90000   31.0000 9.5000
HP300805    NA  08Nov2016 0:00:00.000   25Sep2006 0:00:00.000   2403468.00000   872.90000   31.0000 9.5000
HP301630    10Nov2016 0:00:00.000   10Nov2016 0:00:00.000   NA  1356668.00000   944.70000   29.0000 8.5000
HP301630    10Nov2016 0:00:00.000   10Nov2016 0:00:00.000   13Jun2005 0:00:00.000   NA  944.70000   NA  8.5000
HP303562    09Nov2016 0:00:00.000   09Nov2016 0:00:00.000   07Jul2010 0:00:00.000   2403820.00000   942.60000   32.0000 10.0000
HP303562    09Nov2016 0:00:00.000   NA  07Jul2010 0:00:00.000   2403820.00000   NA  32.0000 NA
HP970489    09Nov2016 0:00:00.000   09Nov2016 0:00:00.000   05Sep2014 0:00:00.000   2428800.00000   887.40000   30.8000 NA
HP970489    09Nov2016 0:00:00.000   09Nov2016 0:00:00.000   05Sep2014 0:00:00.000   2428800.00000   887.40000   30.8000 10.0000
JPRK2894    01Nov2016 0:00:00.000   01Nov2016 0:00:00.000   29Sep2011 0:00:00.000   202392.00000    900.70000   30.6000 10.5000
JPRK2894    01Nov2016 0:00:00.000   NA  29Sep2011 0:00:00.000   NA  900.70000   NA  10.5000
PRK10859    01Nov2016 0:00:00.000   01Nov2016 0:00:00.000   21Nov2014 0:00:00.000   3282376.00000   1229.30000  27.0000 8.0000
PRK10859    01Nov2016 0:00:00.000   01Nov2016 0:00:00.000   21Nov2014 0:00:00.000   NA  NA  27.0000 NA
PRK11982    08Nov2016 0:00:00.000   08Nov2016 0:00:00.000   03Jul2015 0:00:00.000   2010563.00000   1241.50000  28.0000 8.0000
PRK11982    NA  08Nov2016 0:00:00.000   NA  2010563.00000   NA  28.0000 NA
PRK12016    03Nov2016 0:00:00.000   03Nov2016 0:00:00.000   03Dec2014 0:00:00.000   3139159.00000   1188.50000  27.0000 9.0000
PRK12016    NA  NA  NA  NA  1188.50000  NA  9.0000
PRK1290 03Nov2016 0:00:00.000   03Nov2016 0:00:00.000   09May2012 0:00:00.000   6201765.00000   926.90000   26.0000 8.5000
PRK13702    07Nov2016 0:00:00.000   07Nov2016 0:00:00.000   26Oct2016 0:00:00.000   2989858.00000   1250.00000  32.0000 11.0000
PRK14187    08Nov2016 0:00:00.000   08Nov2016 0:00:00.000   13Aug2015 0:00:00.000   2057595.00000   1172.50000  27.0000 8.0000
PRK14294    03Nov2016 0:00:00.000   03Nov2016 0:00:00.000   06Oct2015 0:00:00.000   NA  1241.60000  28.0000 7.5000
PRK2191 07Nov2016 0:00:00.000   07Nov2016 0:00:00.000   15Feb2010 0:00:00.000   471741.00000    998.00000   32.0000 10.5000
PRK2460 10Nov2016 0:00:00.000   10Nov2016 0:00:00.000   25Sep2015 0:00:00.000   2865224.40000   1235.10000  28.0000 8.0000
PRK3510 02Nov2016 0:00:00.000   02Nov2016 0:00:00.000   21Oct2014 0:00:00.000   575628.00000    1236.60000  26.5000 9.5000
PRK3522 08Nov2016 0:00:00.000   08Nov2016 0:00:00.000   30Sep2014 0:00:00.000   2694729.00000   1196.50000  27.0000 8.0000
PRK3579 05Nov2016 0:00:00.000   05Nov2016 0:00:00.000   02Sep2015 0:00:00.000   2951465.00000   1219.20000  28.0000 7.5000
PRK3893 09Nov2016 0:00:00.000   09Nov2016 0:00:00.000   08Aug2014 0:00:00.000   2910361.00000   1173.48000  28.5400 9.6200
PRK3893 09Nov2016 0:00:00.000   09Nov2016 0:00:00.000   08Aug2014 0:00:00.000   2910361.00000   NA  28.5400 9.6200
PRK5    03Nov2016 0:00:00.000   03Nov2016 0:00:00.000   07Oct2015 0:00:00.000   NA  1245.50000  27.0000 9.0000
```

I want to replace the '**NA**' values by either immediate preceding value or immediate post value for each group of '**MC**' such that the final table should look like as below:

```
MC  StartDate   EndDate LWID    KMT DAFR    FTR FSR
HP300805    08Nov2016 0:00:00.000   08Nov2016 0:00:00.000   25Sep2006 0:00:00.000   2403468.00000   872.90000   31.0000 9.5000
HP300805    08Nov2016 0:00:00.000   08Nov2016 0:00:00.000   25Sep2006 0:00:00.000   2403468.00000   872.90000   31.0000 9.5000
HP301630    10Nov2016 0:00:00.000   10Nov2016 0:00:00.000   13Jun2005 0:00:00.000   1356668.00000   944.70000   29.0000 8.5000
HP301630    10Nov2016 0:00:00.000   10Nov2016 0:00:00.000   13Jun2005 0:00:00.000   1356668.00000   944.70000   29.0000 8.5000
HP303562    09Nov2016 0:00:00.000   09Nov2016 0:00:00.000   07Jul2010 0:00:00.000   2403820.00000   942.60000   32.0000 10.0000
HP303562    09Nov2016 0:00:00.000   09Nov2016 0:00:00.000   07Jul2010 0:00:00.000   2403820.00000   942.60000   32.0000 10.0000
HP970489    09Nov2016 0:00:00.000   09Nov2016 0:00:00.000   05Sep2014 0:00:00.000   2428800.00000   887.40000   30.8000 10.0000
HP970489    09Nov2016 0:00:00.000   09Nov2016 0:00:00.000   05Sep2014 0:00:00.000   2428800.00000   887.40000   30.8000 10.0000
JPRK2894    01Nov2016 0:00:00.000   01Nov2016 0:00:00.000   29Sep2011 0:00:00.000   202392.00000    900.70000   30.6000 10.5000
JPRK2894    01Nov2016 0:00:00.000   01Nov2016 0:00:00.000   29Sep2011 0:00:00.000   202392.00000    900.70000   30.6000 10.5000
PRK10859    01Nov2016 0:00:00.000   01Nov2016 0:00:00.000   21Nov2014 0:00:00.000   3282376.00000   1229.30000  27.0000 8.0000
PRK10859    01Nov2016 0:00:00.000   01Nov2016 0:00:00.000   21Nov2014 0:00:00.000   3282376.00000   1229.30000  27.0000 8.0000
PRK11982    08Nov2016 0:00:00.000   08Nov2016 0:00:00.000   03Jul2015 0:00:00.000   2010563.00000   1241.50000  28.0000 8.0000
PRK11982    08Nov2016 0:00:00.000   08Nov2016 0:00:00.000   03Jul2015 0:00:00.000   2010563.00000   1241.50000  28.0000 8.0000
PRK12016    03Nov2016 0:00:00.000   03Nov2016 0:00:00.000   03Dec2014 0:00:00.000   3139159.00000   1188.50000  27.0000 9.0000
PRK12016    03Nov2016 0:00:00.000   03Nov2016 0:00:00.000   03Dec2014 0:00:00.000   3139159.00000   1188.50000  27.0000 9.0000
PRK1290 03Nov2016 0:00:00.000   03Nov2016 0:00:00.000   09May2012 0:00:00.000   6201765.00000   926.90000   26.0000 8.5000
PRK13702    07Nov2016 0:00:00.000   07Nov2016 0:00:00.000   26Oct2016 0:00:00.000   2989858.00000   1250.00000  32.0000 11.0000
PRK14187    08Nov2016 0:00:00.000   08Nov2016 0:00:00.000   13Aug2015 0:00:00.000   2057595.00000   1172.50000  27.0000 8.0000
PRK14294    03Nov2016 0:00:00.000   03Nov2016 0:00:00.000   06Oct2015 0:00:00.000   0   1241.60000  28.0000 7.5000
PRK2191 07Nov2016 0:00:00.000   07Nov2016 0:00:00.000   15Feb2010 0:00:00.000   471741.00000    998.00000   32.0000 10.5000
PRK2460 10Nov2016 0:00:00.000   10Nov2016 0:00:00.000   25Sep2015 0:00:00.000   2865224.40000   1235.10000  28.0000 8.0000
PRK3510 02Nov2016 0:00:00.000   02Nov2016 0:00:00.000   21Oct2014 0:00:00.000   575628.00000    1236.60000  26.5000 9.5000
PRK3522 08Nov2016 0:00:00.000   08Nov2016 0:00:00.000   30Sep2014 0:00:00.000   2694729.00000   1196.50000  27.0000 8.0000
PRK3579 05Nov2016 0:00:00.000   05Nov2016 0:00:00.000   02Sep2015 0:00:00.000   2951465.00000   1219.20000  28.0000 7.5000
PRK3893 09Nov2016 0:00:00.000   09Nov2016 0:00:00.000   08Aug2014 0:00:00.000   2910361.00000   1173.48000  28.5400 9.6200
PRK3893 09Nov2016 0:00:00.000   09Nov2016 0:00:00.000   08Aug2014 0:00:00.000   2910361.00000   1173.48000  28.5400 9.6200
PRK5    03Nov2016 0:00:00.000   03Nov2016 0:00:00.000   07Oct2015 0:00:00.000   0   1245.50000  27.0000 9.0000
```

**Please note that where ever there are single rows, means no prior or post observations are available, replace NAs with 0**

I also want to calculate LAG value for DAFR.

I wanted to do it in R but don't know how. Can someone help?

What I am doing is like that:

```
# Is there NAs, if yes, replace them with 0
which(is.na(DATA$DAFR))
DATA$DAFR[is.na(DATA$DAFR)] <- 0

which(is.na(DATA$FTR))
DATA$FTR[is.na(DATA$FTR)] <- 0

which(is.na(DATA$FSR))
DATA$FSR[is.na(DATA$FSR)] <- 0
```

and for lag I was able to use this at least for KMT

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
DATA1 <- 
  DATA %>%
  arrange(MC, StartDate) %>% 
  group_by(MC) %>%
  replace_na(KMT = ifelse(is.na(lag(KMT))==T, (ifelse(is.na(lead(KMT))==T, 0, lead(KMT))), lag(KMT)))
```

I don't know but I am not getting results and lots of NAs still there.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is the `fill` function in tidyr. https://blog.rstudio.org/2015/09/13/tidyr-0-3-0/

So something like:

```
DATA %>%
     arrange(MC, StartDate) %>% 
     fill(KMT)
```

Comment: corrected `  replace_na(KMT = ifelse(is.na(lag(KMT))==T, (ifelse(is.na(lead(KMT))==T, 0, lead(KMT))), lag(KMT)))
`  but it is saying `replace_na` function not found. whereas it is there on the doc page you gave link for.

Comment: Hello Zeek. The correct way to comment is not to try to modify my answer... but if you have something to say, add as a comment. Furthermore, please try my answer. Type `library(tidyr)` and then what I wrote exactly, no `replace_na` or anything.

Comment: Agree. I will follow that :)

Comment: I found the error... `replace_na()` is a part of `tidyr` package. and It worked.